# $scope.$watch not keeping two controllers in sync?

Tags: angularjs

I have a user object that is retrieved by the user service. I want to know the best way to keep all references to this User object in sync across my App.  (I.e across different controllers) without using UI Provider.

I thought it was just to make a reference by using a factory but nothing is happening.

Here is my **factory**:

```
angular.module('app').factory('userFactory', function ($http) {
    function login (username, password) {
      return $http.post('/login/login', {
        username: username,
        password: password
      }).then(function success (response) {
        return response.data;
      })
})

    var user = {
      login: login
    };


    return user;
```

And here is one **Controller:**

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $location, UserFactory) {

    $scope.login = function (username, password) {
      UserFactory.login(username, password).then(function success (response) {
        $scope.user = response.user;
      });
    };
```

And my second controller:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('HeadCtrl', function ($scope, $location, UserFactory) {

    $scope.login = function (username, password) {
      UserFactory.login(username, password).then(function success (response) {
        $scope.user = response.user;
      });
    };
```

So, if each of these are used simultaneously in my app, how do I make sure that the $scope.user is exactly the same between the two.  (So that, if I log in via one controller, the logged in status changes in the second?

I tried this in each controller:

```
$scope.$watch('user', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  console.log('Something changed');
}, true);
```

But it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Store the logged-in user in the `UserFactory` so that it can be shared among multiple controllers.

```
angular.module('app').factory('UserFactory', function ($http) {
  var user = {
    currentUser: null,
    login: login
  };

  return user;

  function login (username, password) {
    return $http.post('/login/login', {
      username: username,
      password: password
    }).then(function success (response) {
      user.currentUser = response.data;
      return user.currentUser;
    });
  }
}
```

Then, watch the factory's property and synchronize it with `$scope` in the controllers.

```
$scope.user = UserFactory.currentUser;
$scope.$watch(function () {
  return UserFactory.currentUser;
}, function () {
  $scope.user = UserFactory.currentUser;
});

$scope.login = function (username, password) {
  UserFactory.login(username, password);
};
```